# Parameter is always null WCF post method

Tags: android, wcf, rest

I have a WCF restful service, In that I have a POST method. When calling that from android client the parameter object is always null on WCF method. Below is the code of android and WCF service.

WCF Interface:

```
   [OperationContract(Name = "datetime1")]        
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat =   WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "datetime1", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
    ResponseMessage GetResponse(RequestData req);
```

WCF Method Implementation:

```
public ResponseMessage GetResponse(RequestData req)
    {
        string s = req == null ? "Yes" : "No";
        ResponseMessage msg = new ResponseMessage()
        {
            DateTime = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(),
            Error = "none",
            hoursLeft = 5,
            IsTrialExpired = false,
            Response = "My Response " + s,
            token = "token here"
        };
        return msg;
    }
```

Android client, calling code:

```
RequestData requestData = new RequestData("1","2","3","4");
JSONStringer req = new JSONStringer();
    try {
        req.object()
                .key("UserId").value(requestData.getUserId())
                .key("AppId").value(requestData.getAppId())
                .key("ThirdParty").value(requestData.getThirdParty())
                .key("UserToken").value(requestData.getUserToken())
                .endObject();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

String url = "<my method url>";

//instantiates httpClient to make request
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        //url with the post data
        HttpPost httPost = new HttpPost(url);

        //passes the results to a string builder/entity
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(req);

        //sets the post request as the resulting string
        httPost.setEntity(se);
        httPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");


        HttpResponse httpresponse = httpClient.execute(httPost);

        InputStream inputStream = httpresponse.getEntity().getContent();
        if (inputStream != null) {
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
                res += line;

            inputStream.close();
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return res;
```

Request JSon:

```
{"UserId":"1","AppId":"2","ThirdParty":"3","UserToken":"4"}
```

Response JSon:

```
{"datetime1Result":{"DateTime":"7\/31\/2014","Error":"none","IsTrialExpired":false,"Response":"My Response Yes","hoursLeft":5,"token":"token here"}}
```

Note: notice the "Yes" in the response string, It is because the object is null.

My RequestData class:

```
[DataContract]
public class RequestData
{
    [DataMember]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string AppId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string ThirdParty { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public String UserToken { get; set; }
}
```

What am I doing wrong ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the reference name of JSONStringer.
the reference names(req) of JSONStringer and StringEntity both are same

Comment: check by Removing the body style wrapped in the contract and also debug the android code whether you are able to convert your RequestData object to JSON object. before that check your service is able to accept the json object from fiddler

Comment: I am able to get response from service. but the object is null.

i am using
    `string s = req == null ? "Yes" : "No";`
to check if the object is null.

in the response from service I am returning the values of `s`.

Comment: The request JSON should be like below format {"req":{"UserId":"1","AppId":"2","ThirdParty":"3","UserToken":"4"}}

Comment: While debugging check the json string whether it is matching above format or not

Comment: {"req":{"UserId":"1","AppId":"2","ThirdParty":"3","UserToken":"4"}}

Comment: Thanks man, it solved the issue :)

I was missing `"req"` in the json request.

Comment: req.object().key("req").object()
                .key("UserId").value(requestData.getUserId())
                .key("AppId").value(requestData.getAppId())
                .key("ThirdParty").value(requestData.getThirdParty())
                .key("UserToken").value(requestData.getUserToken())
                .endObject();

Comment: is the below string is invalid ?

`{"requestDataDTO":
"{\"req\":{\"UserId\":\"1\",\"AppId\":\"2\",\"ThirdParty\":\"3\",\"UserToken\":\"4\"}},
{\"req1\":{\"UserId\":\"1\",\"AppId\":\"-33\",\"ThirdParty\":\"3\",\"UserToken\":\"4\"}}"}`

I want to wrap and pass two object inside one object, in one of my web service method.

Comment: do you want to convert a class into json object that class hold another object, something like below code   public class StoreAndProductDetails
    {
        public ProductFeed listProductFeed { get; set; }
        public PriceFeed listPriceFeed { get; set; }
        public StoreFeed listStoreFeed { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Yes, My requirement is to send more then two class object as parameter for that I created another class which will hold these class object and I'll send that class object as parameter to my POST method.

Comment: when you convert the custom class into JSON it automatically convert the inner properties in JSON format, try it this should work